# Deleting menu item results index error ("source not found")

Tags: vb.net, menu

In VB.Net 2010, whenever I delete a menu item on a Windows Form (a Mainmenu1 object), an exception is thrown at run-time suggesting that there is an index value missing -- essentially a "source not found" error.  Do I need to go into the Mainmenu1 object on the bottom of the Form at design time and do something?  (BTW, I have also tried deleting the source code for the menu item, and then the menu item, and the exception is still thrown).

Basically, something is occurring that is not allowing me to simply delete a menu item, and get a successful run thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem.  The simple fix is to restore the menu by clicking undo.  Then run the code to make sure it still works.  When you have done this, CLOSE visual studio.  Then open VS and load your project.  Delete the item from the menu and run the project.  Everything should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify whether you were trying to delete the menu or menu item during **run time**, or during **design time**.

You said, an exception, indicating an index value was missing, thrown at run time. I think it might be depending on how you deleted the menu item. You didn't mention how you deleted the menu item. 
Normally, when you choose a menu item from a menu at design time, and press the Delete key, it disappeared. And, the program still works fine.

And, another possibility, is that your form window designer and the background designer code is not properly synced. 
You might know that, every .NET form objects, have their background designer code, which serves as a schema for everything on the form. 
When you add a button onto the form, the Visual Studio add a line of code in the designer code file (normally if your form name is **form1**, the designer code file is **form1.designer.vb** or **cs** or whatever). When you change the background colour of the button, designer code file add a line of code to set the button's background colour.

So, you see, in your case, when you delete the menu item, your designer code file probably didn't successfully remove the code relating to that menu item. So, it throws an exception at run time. 

Maybe, it's because of your Visual Studio installation.

So, my suggestion is, you should try debugging the project, line by line, by running the project with F6 or F11 (sorry, I don't remember the exact key, but you can find it in the Debug menu).

I hope I made a good sense for your problem!

Comment: I think you should specify exactly, how you deleted the menu item. Cause that problem usually occur when menu items are deleted programmatically at runtime.